# How to auto-fill user inputs when installing rpm package in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

I have a rpm package which during installation, it asks for user inputs. I want to auto-fill my inputs. 
I tried: 
`printf '2\n2\n' | rpm -ivh foo.rpm` 
But, it still asks for user input. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RPMs *cannot* interact with the user. End of story. There are various reasons found sprinkled about the internet.